# Link not working in ie8 compatibility mode

Tags: jquery, css, xhtml

I have the code below which is just a link for the user to login, when pressed it shows a login box using jquery. It works fine in IE8 but when the compatibility mode is enabled the link doesnt work at all, it like it isn't even there.

```
<body>

    <script type="text/javascript">

    make_request();

    var clicked = 0;

     $(document).ready(function() 
     {

            $('#login_top').corners();
            $('#points_top').corners();   

            $('#login_box').hide();
            $('#login_box').corners();  

            $('#login_link').click(function() 
            {               
                $('#login_box').fadeIn(2000);
                $('#username').focus();

            });

            $('#close_link').click(function() 
            {
                $('#login_box').hide("slow");
            });

    });     

    </script>    

    <div id="login_top">

        <a href="javascript:void(0);" id="login_link"><img src="images/user.png" alt="Login" />Login</a>


    </div>
```

I havent included the whole page as this is the only area where the problem occurs, the css is below:

```
#login_top
{
    background-color: #000000;
    text-align: center;
    margin-left: 20px;  
    margin-top: 5px;
    width: 70px;
    padding: 5px;   
    font-size: 16px;
}

#login_top a
{
    text-decoration: none;
    color: #ffffff;
}

#login_top img
{
    border-style: none;
}
```

Any advice?

Thanks :)

Comment: Why are you using IE8's 'break websites', I mean 'compatibility' mode?

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
<a href="javascript:void(0);" id...
```

to just

```
<a href="#" id...
```